# Checking whether a domain contains stop words

Tags: php

OK, have checked previous answers and tried some other examples firstly
using `in_array` bit it didn't do what I wanted and after reading some comments I'm also trying using `strpos` but still not right.

```
$thisWebsite = "siterude.com";          
$stopwords = array("bad", "rude");

foreach ( $stopwords as $string ) 
{
    if ( strpos( $string, $thisWebsite) !== FALSE )
     { $dontsave = "1"; }
  }
```

So basically I want that if it finds any of the `$stopwords` in `$thisWebsite` then `$dontsave = 1` for use later.

It seems to work sometimes but not reliable enough as too many slip through.
Is there a better way of picking out words within a longer word and not exact matches?

Comment: On a side note: Badwords filtering is a bit counterproductive. Someone, somewhere, is going to find a way around it. You'll be writing a HUGE array if you want to be a bit affective, which will eventually result in a very slow website.

Comment: Thanks - should have noticed that - my apologies will go for a coffee :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strpos($string, $thisWebsite)` means find `$thisWebsite` in `$string`, which is not what you wanted. You want to find the `$string` in `$thisWebsite`. Just switch them around, and you're good.

Check PHP manual for details on [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos).

```
mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Comment: Thanks - should have noticed that - my apologies will go for a coffee :-)